# Android admob can we re-modify native advance ads layout according to app UI

Tags: android, admob

I found native advance ads example on github. I found in code there is two layout file one for install_ads layout file and another for website content layout file. So my question is that can we modify these layout file according to application UI. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking whether you can use your own layout files with Native Advanced Ads, the answer is yes. Native ads are designed to be customized so that you can make them look natural and unobtrusive in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can completely modify the design in layout for both app install and content ads as per your app. Designing the ad as per you app's colour and  pattern so that the ad feels more native to your app is it's purpose. 
The two layouts app install and content are for the two kinds of ads:

- App install we display the ads which are for the install of an app from store hence having texts like "install" "download now" on the ad
- Content ad will redirect to a website, hence with texts like "visit stie" and "order now" on the action button.